# Bootstrap modal fires twice when close and reopen

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a login form modal invoked by clicking a button. And the modal is call from external file with ajax load. However, if I close and reopen the modal. The modal will launch twice and double modal-backdrop class will appear and I cant use and function of the modal. Also, I found that the console message appear: [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #loginForm: .

I try tp remove the modal class when the modal hidden. However, It doesn't work.

//jquery

```
$('a.login').click(function(event) {
  var url = "userlogin.php";
  $('.login-container').load(url,function(result){
      $('#modalLoginForm').modal({show:true});

        });

});

$("#modalLoginForm").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
  resetMyForm();
  $("#modalLoginForm").remove();
});

$('.loginbutton').click(function(event) {
// prevent the default submit
alert("haha");
event.preventDefault();
var form = $('#loginForm');
//alert(form);
$.ajax({
    url: "authentication.php", 
    type: "POST",
    // use the forms data
    data: form.serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {    
        console.log( "Processing..." );
    },
    success: function( response ){
        // do sth with the response

        if(response == "OK") {
           // credentials verified
           // redirect

         location.reload();
        }else{
           // credentials incorrect
           // append errormessage to modal
          form.closest('.modal-body').append('<div class="error text- 
          danger">*'+response+'</div>');

          }
          },
    error: function( response ) {
       console.log(response);
    }

    });
    return false;
    });
```

//index.php

```
 <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary btn-rounded login" data- 
 toggle="modal">Login</a>
<div class="login-container"></div>
```

//userlogin.php

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalLoginForm" tabindex="-1" 
    role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content bg-light">
    <div class="modal-header bg-dark">
    <h4 class="col-sm-12 text-center text-white comp ">Sign in</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body mx-3">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
  <form id="loginForm"  method="post">
    <div class="md-form mb-5">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
      <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" 
     for="defaultForm-email">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control validate">
    </div>

    <div class="md-form mb-4">
      <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
       <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" 
     for="defaultForm-pass">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control validate">

      </div>
    </div>
    <form>
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center bg-primary">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default text-white comp 
   loginbutton">Login</button>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>

   <script src="js/modal.js"></script>
```

I want to launch only one modal when I close and reopen. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it like this in the JS, and please, use the "native" options to show and hide the modal aka modal.('toggle')

My advice, move all the modal except the content inside the modal-body to index.php, and leave the form (#loginForm) in userlogin.php, then change your javascript for this one:

```
$('a.login').click(function(event) {
  var url = "userlogin.php";
  $('#modalLoginForm').find('.modal-body').load(url)
  $('#modalLoginForm').modal('toggle');
});

$("#modalLoginForm").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
  resetMyForm();
});
```

Sometimes, when modals show duplicated or straight not working it is because jQuery, or Boostrap imports are in the wrong order or duplicated, but in your case, I think its just the javascript that is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. However, I use above code and cannot launch the modal. I added alert(url) function to ensure click event is triggered. But the modal cannot be launch.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your suggestion help me to solve the modal problem. However, It  trigger my login button click as a multiply number. When first time open modal and click login alert 2 times, then 4 times, 8 times. Thanks for helping me. Code updated in above column

Comment: I solve the problem by $('.loginbutton').unbind().click(function(event) .

Comment: @shelvey33 Glad I helped! Please upvote and mark as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

You call modal twice: with `data-toggle` and with `modal` function

Try this code in your `index.php`:

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-secondary btn-rounded login">Login</a>
<div class="login-container"></div>
```

And add some verification if the modal already loaded to your page before calling `load`

Comment: Thanks. I tried above code and I found that the backdrop appear 1 second then disappear immediately.